Configuring PyCharm to Recognize Local Python Packages within Project Structure
I am working in a project in PyCharm with a conda environment. I have a root directoy that is not installed as a package, however there are multiple subdirectories that need to be installed as importable packages. My folder structure looks as follows:
project_root/
├── .env
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── python/
    ├── tt_job/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── calculate.py
    │   └── main.py
    └── library/
        └── road/
            └── properties.py

My python/blob_project/main.py is the function I am mostly using, and it imports the following packages:
from library.road import properties
from tt_job import calculate

The problem is that PyCharm does not recognise them (Unresolved reference 'library') nor can I run the code (NameError: name 'library' is not defined). I do not understand how I would go about installing those packages, that they can be found.
I have tried to run pip install -e . however that results in: Successfully installed UNKNOWN-0.0.0

This is a reference to a similar if not the same issue here. unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Thanks, this helped me solve it for both running my code and PyCharm recognising the imports.

I encountered the same issue once on my projects. I am using PyCharm as well.
I solved it by writing what is bellow before importing the library :
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

Like that your system should be able to find "library".
Regards,

Thanks, this was a quick solve for succesfully importing the folders. To fix PyCharm recognising the imports as well, this link helped me further unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm
